# $_POST persistency using an AJAX call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, response

I am trying to set up a comment system, in which when the users sends the comment it is displayed on their screen as if it were already stored on the database.
My question is: what would happen if the users send comments and then navigate away
(or most specifically close the window immediately) or they lose connection after the ajax post?

On the code side I have `ajax({})`...

Then I have code that takes the user input from the textarea and adds it to a div.

This means that the user gets to see the comment they entered instantaneously. But I would like to be sure if the server will get the post info even if the connection was lost, window was closed or the user navigated away.

---

**More info for the question:**

A user sends a post to the server with 1mb of values, then right after one millisecond
he/she clicked on the button that made the post the browser window was closed.

Does the server receive and parse the response with `ignore_user_abort(true);`
inside the file; was the post info received?

Any difference if it were get instead of post for this case?

Assume `website.com?myget=value`

Trying to connect then closing the window immediately, on a browser window for example,
just hitting that on the address bar and then closing very right away, imagine it to
be automatically.

step 1 go to `website.com?myget=value` (don't wait at all for any server response, just
straight away (a millisecond or whatever it takes the script to do so) close completely
the window.

Would `$_GET['myget']` be received server side at index.php of website.com?

Comment: You need to cut down on the run-on sentences, bro. I am so lost understanding what you wrote.

Comment: At least for `ignore_user_abort`: _PHP will not detect that the user has aborted the connection until an attempt is made to send information to the client_. Save your data before doing any echo/ print.

Comment: @SalmanA `ignore_user_abort` will cause the script not die if you try to output anything. So this advice isn't necessary if `ignore_user_abort(TRUE)` is called.

Answer (score 1):

This is a UX problem, not a technical one. What you want to do is display the new comment only after it has been stored.  The workflow should go something like this:

1. User types message
2. User clicks on "submit" button
3. System grays out "submit" button and displays a message that reads,
   "Posting..."
4. When System can confirm that the message has been successfully
   stored, System will remove "Posting..." text and display actual new
   message.

This way the user knows not to close their browser or navigate away until the request is done.

---

Alternatively you can you [`onbeforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onbeforeunload) to warn your users to wait before closing the browser or navigating away. Workflow being something like:

> **Prerequisite:** You have a persistent counter somewhere (cookie, local storage, hidden field, etc). When the page loads, it starts at **0**.

1. User types message
2. User clicks on "submit" button
3. AJAX request is sent
4. Counter is increased by **1**
5. Request is complete, you get a response (whether it's successful or not - error handling is another issue), decrease the counter by **1**

If at any point, the [`unload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onunload) event is triggered, System will check the counter.  If greater than **0**, warn the user that their request has not been completed and that they might loose their comment (a-la-Gmail).

Comment: It's good, but I want to achieve a fast look effect on this one.

Comment: Then I foresee another issue. The speed in which requests are completed vary per request. What if the user starts rapid-firing comments? Comments 1, 2, 3, 4 may get stored in 3, 1, 4, 2 order. This problem is not impossible to solve, but it _is_ something you'll need to be aware of if you're going to allow users to asynchronously add content in parallel.

Comment: true, would have to at least take in consideration timestamps, to make them client side and send these along the post instead of generating for the database because yeah, that could happen.

Comment: Don't trust client-side time. Wrong time set on computer, different time zones, etc.  Usually it's best to have only one, stable, "time giver" (that's my super technical term).

Answer (score 1):

Will add my five cents. With `ajax({})` you will ask browser to start communication with your server. It needs some time to establish connection (ping time) and send data to server. Both parts require some time to be completed. In order for PHP to start execution, browser must sent all data it has to send. No matter is it POST or GET. If user will break sending procedure (browser crashed, tab closed, computer turned off) PHP will not even be started. For instance, you can try to send some large file and see with a debugger when PHP script will be started - only after file is delivered completely (you can even close your browser before file is uploaded and see if your script is executed at all). It makes sense to start PHP execution only after all data delivered to server and ignore connections broken before data delivered. Otherwise there could be problems with data being corrupted. And nobody wants that. Plus, imagine that PHP is started before everything is delivered to server: you would never be sure that `$_POST["something"]` is not available because it was never entered by user or its data is not yet delivered.

There is no difference if you are using regular form submit or XMLHTTPRequest. In both cases browser need some time to establish connection with server and pass a data to it.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, whatever action you perform against the server will continue to be executed until such a point as the PHP running on the server tries to output results back to the browser. Only at this point will PHP check whether the connection still exists and do whatever is should do based on the user abort settings.  So, if for example you wanted to receive the post, update a database entry, and then echo back some sort of success message, the database activity should continue so long as you have not made any output before the database is queried.

POST vs. GET makes no difference in this behavior.

Comment: But does the connection actually get "established" just with using ajax({}),  I really don't need a connection in between client server, just for the server to receive $_POST no matter what if I wrote up the ajax with the data. Was wondering if large strings (assume 500 kb) on a very slow connection client side would actually get to the server just by stating the action of posting to it. Will the server receive or does it depend on the client at all except for it just sending the request.

Comment: @lbennet With large POST's it will take the client some period of item to send the request over the wire, so if the user closed the browser or lost power or something like that, they certainly might not have completed the entire TCP communication.  How that is handled by the server may vary. I would think in most cases the server would discard the request.

Comment: Alright, but doing a script that goes to site.com?myget=value and closes without waiting at all for any server output is more than good enough for site.com to have received $_GET for this basic example, I don't assume more than 10 kb comments at all, the problem would be if it wouldn't be enough for the server just to receive the request or if the async ajax call is not fired before going on with more js code. My worries are for post not to be received, just received, but if the query is executed, the XMLHttpRequest is started - that is enough for the server ?